# cannot reslove method settext

Tags: java

[image: вопрос]
На рисунке видно ошибку
Когда я переношу условие в другой блок кода для метода settext компилятор находит аргумент (он работает) но при этом нельзя сравнить input что делать?

Comment: На рисунке ни черта не видно. Приведите код в текстовом виде. Что за переменные `inputX1`, `inputZ1` и т.п.?

Comment: видимо метод settext() не находится в этом классе - вот вам и подсвечивается эта ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо перед inputX1.setText(""); указать имя Суперкласса (В моём случае это SimpleGUI)

После если JTextField объявлен не static компилятор предложит сделать его static (Необходимо сделать его static)

После вам все-равно как у меня может выдать ошибку cannot reslove symbol settext
В таком случае settest необходимо указать как setText (большая буква T)

Было:
inputX1.settext("");

Стало:
SimpleGUI.inputX1.setText("");